# Angular HTTP dependency in component

Tags: angular

I am just playing around - trying to load data from a static JSON file to begin learning angular templating.

I have googled and found a few examples, but implement a service which I want to avoid until I get a better grasp on things...

Here is my code:

**app.module.ts**

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {RouteReuseStrategy} from '@angular/router';

import {IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy} from '@ionic/angular';
import {SplashScreen} from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import {StatusBar} from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {AppRoutingModule} from './app-routing.module';

import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    entryComponents: [],
    imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule],
    providers: [
        StatusBar,
        SplashScreen,
        HttpClientModule,
        {provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy}
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule {
}
```

**tags.page.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-tags',
    templateUrl: './tags.page.html',
    styleUrls: ['./tags.page.scss'],
})

export class TagsPage implements OnInit {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.http.get("./assets/tags.json");
    }

}
```

When I load the tags component however I am bombed by all these errors - none of which are helping me much, at the moment (consider me a newbie).

```
> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError:
> StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[TagsPage -> HttpClient]:   
> StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[TagsPage -> HttpClient]: 
>     NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient! NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[TagsPage -> HttpClient]:   
> StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[TagsPage -> HttpClient]: 
>     NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!
>     at NullInjector.get (core.js:778)
>     at resolveToken (core.js:2564)
>     at tryResolveToken (core.js:2490)
>     at StaticInjector.get (core.js:2353)
>     at resolveToken (core.js:2564)
>     at tryResolveToken (core.js:2490)
>     at StaticInjector.get (core.js:2353)
>     at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:26403)
>     at NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:27491)
>     at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:26403)
>     at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:797)
>     at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:754)
>     at zone-evergreen.js:858
>     at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
>     at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:34182)
>     at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:390)
>     at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:168)
>     at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone-evergreen.js:559)
>     at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone-evergreen.js:469)
>     at invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:1603)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HttpClientModule` should be included in the modules `imports` array, not the `providers`.

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    entryComponents: [],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule, 
        IonicModule.forRoot(), 
        AppRoutingModule, 
        HttpClientModule // ← moved to imports
    ],
    providers: [
        StatusBar,
        SplashScreen,
        {provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy}
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Comment: Haha...total newbie mistake my bad. :)

Comment: @Alex.Barylski - these things happen to the best of us.